# How compile from the Visual Studio Command Prompt?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to compile the following sources and the header:

**5-book.cpp**

```
#include "book.h"

int main() 
try {
    string isbn = "0-321-99278-4";
    Book b {"harry potter","jk rowling",1998,isbn};
}
catch(runtime_error& e) {
    cerr<<"error: "<<e.what()<<'\n';
}
```

**book.h**

```
#include <std_lib_facilities.h>

    class Book {
        static const int min_copyright = 1900;
public:
    Book(string t,string a,int c,string s);
private:
    string title;
    string author;
    int copyright;
    string isbn;
};

bool is_isbn(string& isn);
int skip_int(string& s,int i);
bool alphameric(char c);
```

**book.cpp**

```
#include "book.h"

Book::Book(string t,string a,int c,string s) : title {t},author {a},copyright {c},isbn {s} {
    if(c<min_copyright) error("not valid copyright year");
    if(!is_isbn(s)) error("not valid ISBN");
}

bool is_isbn(string& isbn) {
    int i = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j<3; ++j) {
        i = skip_int(isbn,i);
        if(i==0 || i==isbn.size() || isbn[i++]!='-') return false;
    }
    if(i==isbn.size() || !alphameric(isbn[i++])) return false;
    if(i!=isbn.size()) return false;
    return true;
}

int skip_int(string& s,int i) {
    int j = i;
    for(; j<s.size() && ('0'<=s[j] && s[j]<='9'); ++j);
    if(i==j) return 0;
    return j;
}

bool alphameric(char c) {
    return (('0'<=c && c<='9') || ('a'<=c && c<='z') || ('A'<=c && c<='Z'))? true : false;
}
```

But I get the following error.

```
Compilador de optimización de C/C++ de Microsoft (R) versión 19.26.28806 para x86
(C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.

5-book.cpp
book.cpp
Generating code...
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.26.28806.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:5-book.exe
5-book.obj
book.obj
book.obj : error LNK2005: already defined "class std::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned int,32,624,397,31,2567483615,11,4294967295,7,2636928640,15,4022730752,18,1812433253> & __cdecl get_rand(void)" (?get_rand@@YAAAV?$mersenne_twister_engine@I$0CA@$0CHA@$0BIN@$0BP@$0JJAILANP@$0L@$0PPPPPPPP@$06$0JNCMFGIA@$0P@$0OPMGAAAA@$0BC@$0GMAHIJGF@@std@@XZ) en 5-book.obj
book.obj : error LNK2005: already defined "void __cdecl seed_randint(int)" (?seed_randint@@YAXH@Z) en 5-book.obj
5-book.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more symbols defined simultaneously
```

What I may be doing wrong with this code, or with the command?

Comment: Apparently, somewhere in the code hidden behind `...` you are calling functions named `get_rand` and `seed_randint`, but you haven't actually implemented these functions.

Comment: [mcve] and ideally set your error messages to english.

Comment: We cannot help you, because you stripped out the broken code from your files then didn't check that your question still made sense before submitting it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik These are functions implemented in the library #include <std_lib_facilities.h>, but I don't use them in my code. I have used this same library without problems before when I only compile one source file.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings there isn't any mention to any part of the code I wrote in the error message, but since you ask I will add it just in case.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont OK, I translated the important parts.

Comment: Ah. You define a function in a header, then include that header in two source files. As a result, you end up with two definitions of the same function, and the linker complains. Either mark those functions `inline`, or put just the declaration in the header, and the definition in a separate source file.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'm sorry, I didn't completely understand. I have updated the post with the complete code now. Where do I move the implementation of the functions? I should have a third source code for that?

Comment: You've shown everything **except** the functions that the linker actually complains about. Anyway - yes, you probably should move their implementations in a third source file, say `std_lib_facilities.cpp`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'm sorry, I was a bit lost since I never did anything with that library before, I just include it and always works for one source file programs. This is just the library that it is used with the Stroustrup C++ book, [std_lib_facilities.h](https://web.archive.org/web/20191220035121/http://stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h)

Comment: Most functions in that header are either templates or marked with `inline`. Two are missed though - `get_rand` and `seed_randint`. They are probably also meant to be `inline`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It is working now after changing to inline. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in your version of Stroustrup's `std_lib_facilities.h`.

Neither `get_rand` nor `seed_randint` is marked `inline`, and since they are defined in a header, their definitions will be embedded in every translation unit that makes use of the header, rather than just once (and not with internal linkage).

[The version on GitHub](https://github.com/BjarneStroustrup/Programming-_Principles_and_Practice_Using_Cpp/blob/master/std_lib_facilities.h) does not have this problem, though ironically that seems to be because it is older.

Comment: This was my problem too with the latest version of the file from Stroustrup's website. (header comment has "Revised June 15 for defaultfloat hack for older GCCs"). My solution was to inline the following: void seed_randint(), default_random_engine& get_rand(). Boy this drove me NUTS!